# batch-job example in spring cloud dataflow

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

batch-job example seems doesn't works when I try deployed it in SpringCloudDataFlow local.
To make test I've used spring-cloud-task 1.2.1.RELEASE and cloud-dataflow-server-local-1.2.3.RELEASE.

To make test I've follow these steps:

- Build spring-cloud-task-samples/batch-job
- Register application in spring dataflow with url
  maven://io.spring.cloud:batch-job:jar:1.2.1.RELEASE and Type Task
- from task tab define task without parameter
- run it

When I say 'seems doesn't works' I mean that in stdout.log I was waiting "Job1 was run" instead, I don't find nothing and stderr was empty.

Am I doing something wrong ?

Thanks for help

Comment: Are you using a real database or the embedded HSQLDB?  What do the jobs and tasks tabs display?  What logs are you looking at (the ones for the server or the ones for the job since the job is run in another JVM)?

Comment: I used embedded HSQLDB, in Tabtask I found executiontab shome executionid without exitcode, end time ecc.ecc.
In Jobs tabs I don't find nothing. I'm seeing jobs logs,

Comment: Please provide the logs from the launch.

Comment: Please check it out . https://pastebin.com/TszkiqXR Thanks

Comment: What version of Spring Cloud Data Flow are you using?  We recently identified a bug where the internal H2 DB isn't available.  You can change to an external database for the time being.  You can also track the issue here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/1628

Comment: Hi, @MichaelMinella removing h2 dependency from task example and use other db it works for me. Now I'm experienced other problem like 'TaskExecution, ID 2 task is already complete' but this is another story. Thanks